# Кнопка меню в android

Tags: меню, android, java

Всем привет.
На смартфоне nexus 5 в при открытии некоторых приложений справа от стандартных кнопок (домой, запущенные приложения, назад) дорисовывается еще одна кнопка. Выглядит она так:

[image: Imgur]

Вопрос: это фишка андроида 4.4 или как-то можно это реализовать в остальных? Я вроде бы никогда такое не встречал. Обычно кнопку меню вешают в ActionBar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта кнопка появляется тогда, когда приложение реализовывает меню, но не делает ActionBar. Появление этой кнопки обычно говорит о том, что приложение спроектировано с нарушением гайдлайнов. Много деталей здесь - [Say Goodbye to the Menu Button](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html).

Comment: Она появляется если в манифесте указана targetSdkVersion ниже 11    
Собственно и предназначена она для приложений, написанных до ActionBar'а

Comment: Но если честно, то можно хитрым хаком в две строки добавить эту кнопку и даже в том случае, если targetSdkVersion > 11. Более того, она будет полностью функциональна.

Comment: KoVadim, поделитесь?

Comment: есть такой вызов

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 

WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN - это просто константа, равная `0x00000400`. Есть ещё одна константа `FLAG_NEEDS_MENU_KEY = 0x40000000`, но она не определена на уровне java кода, только в [си коде](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/input/InputWindow.h).

Никто не мешает подставить явно число. Сам код не пишу, так как это сильный костыль, но если нужно - напишите. Эту строку нужно вызывать для каждой активити.

Comment: Напишите, если не трудно.

Comment: я предоставил достаточно информации, что бы этот код смогли написать. Если Вы не можете этого сделать, Вам рано применять этот код.

Comment: я понял, благодарю.