# Нет кнопки меню на планшете, как его собственно вызвать?

Tags: android

Нет кнопки меню на планшете, как его собственно вызвать? Вот сам код меню, основан на Intent.

```
   @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    this.myMenu = menu;
    MenuItem item = menu.add(0, 1, 0, "На главную");
    item.setIcon(R.drawable.home);
    MenuItem item2 = menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Категории");
    item2.setIcon(R.drawable.cat);
    MenuItem item3 = menu.add(0, 3, 0, "Обновить");
    item3.setIcon(R.drawable.s);
    MenuItem item4 = menu.add(0, 4, 0, "Очистить кэш");
    item4.setIcon(R.drawable.trash);
    MenuItem item5 = menu.add(0, 5, 0, "Выход");
    item5.setIcon(R.drawable.exit);
    MenuItem item6 = menu.add(0, 6, 0, "На предыдущую страницу");
    item6.setIcon(R.drawable.arrowleft);
    menu.add(0, 7, 0, "И тд.");
    return true; 
}
```

Что надо дописать, чтобы начали отображаться эти три точки, вызывающие менюшку?

Comment: Навигация в меню является анти-паттерном UI в андроид. 

[10 анти-паттернов навигации в Android][1]


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/213097/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кнопка меню - это было хорошо, но гугл считает, что это устаревшая вещь и рекомендует использовать ActionBar. Если Вам очень сильно нужна кнопка меню - компилируйте с указанием правильной targetSDK или хорошо поищите на хэшкоде - я писал решение в пару строк, что бы добавить эту кнопку, независимо от версии sdk.

нашел свой же [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/294856/java-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E-%D0%B2-android).