# Как поместить кнопку меню в панель кнопок если нет хардварной кнопки меню?

Tags: java, android

У меня имеется `ToolBar` и кнопка меню на нем, но помимо меню он не выполняет никакой роли. Как поместить кнопку меню в строку управляющих кнопок? Нашел только в каком-то обсуждении, что кнопка меню сама переместится в нижнюю панель кнопок если отсутствует `ToolBar`,  но у меня ничего не перемещается, удаляю бар и все - ни бара ни кнопки. Соответственно на устройстве где кнопка меню хардварная там наверное меню будет адекватно работать даже без `ToolBar`, но как принудительно впихнуть ее на устройстве где все управляющие кнопки на экране?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что Вы будете делать с устройствами где нет ни панели, ни хардварной меню? Насчёт кнопки посмотрите [этот ответ с комментами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/294863/11515) - легального способа это сделать нету.

Comment: хм, мне казалось, что там где нет хардварной обязательно есть программная

Comment: Ну раз Вы задали этот вопрос - значит где-то её нет, не так ли?